# How to get base url with virtual directry?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I have MVC application that is hosted in IIS. The application is a child application of another parent application. The parent application is hosted under
**DefaultWebSite** and the child application is hosted under parent application like below

[image]

SO the URL for child application is `http://www.parent.com/child`

In child application code, how do i get base url?

```
 var baseApplicationUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
```

the code above returns only `http://www.parent.com/`

I can affix `baseApplicationUrl` with `child` string. But different environment may have different virtual directory name. It may not be `child` in other environment. Also in the application can be hosted directly under `DefaultWebSite` as root application. So the code should be able handle all these scenarios